# Free/Paid Silverlight Video Players?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, video, skins

I'm looking for some nice looking silverlight video players to be used on a website.  Similar to this question regarding flash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167072/free-paid-flash-video-players, I'm looking for some good silverlight skins.

Any good resources available? I'm aware of:

- http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-wmv-player/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Microsoft Media Platform Player Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com/releases/view/88970)
2. [Silverlight 2 Video Player on CodePlex](http://sl2videoplayer.codeplex.com/)
3. The ASP.Net MediaPlayer control in the [Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=c22d6a7b-546f-4407-8ef6-d60c8ee221ed&displaylang=en) has some built-in skins that can be customized

Comment: Expression link is dead (as is Expression itself as a standalone product): http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/index.html